# How to make sql query for adding calculated values group by id?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, sum, laravel-query-builder

I had a table with name, negeri and year of start service and end service.I want to get the number of years a person served in a state:

```
  ID | Name     | State   |   yearstart     |    yearend
  -----------------------------------------------------------
  1  | Tom      | Kedah   |      2001       |      2002
  1  | Tom      | Kedah   |      2003       |      2007
  2  | Anne     | Melaka  |      2008       |      2012
  2  | Anne     | Melaka  |      2013       |      2018
  3  | Bill     | KL      |      2000       |      2001
```

I had already tried. but it only calculate the number of years and list all person(with duplicate name and state).

```
   $query = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                ->join('state', 'itemregistrations.StateID', '=', 'state.StateID')
                ->select('itemregistrations.name');

  if($request->input('negeri_perkhidmatan') != '') {
            $query->join('itemregistrationpangkat', 'itemregistrationpangkat.itemRegistrationID', '=', 'itemregistrations.itemRegistrationID')
                ->where('itemregistrationpangkat.StateID', $request->input('negeri_perkhidmatan'));           
        }

  if(request('tempoh_negeri')) {
            $query->whereRaw('yearend - yearstart >= ?', [request('tempoh_negeri')]);  
        }
```

The results display:

```
  ID | Name     | State   |    years   
  ---------------------------------------
  1  | Tom      | Kedah   |      1      
  1  | Tom      | Kedah   |      4     
  2  | Anne     | Melaka  |      4       
  2  | Anne     | Melaka  |      5      
  3  | Bill     | KL      |      1
```

The result should be:

```
  ID | Name     | State   |    years   
  ---------------------------------------
  1  | Tom      | Kedah   |      5      
  2  | Anne     | Melaka  |      9            
  3  | Bill     | KL      |      1
```

The result displayed in browser is fetched using ajax. I don't put it here.

Comment: just add `groupBy('ID')` to your query

Comment: I cannot simply use groupby and i already tried before, it failed. Because it it not counting but selecting columns with different values. See the current sql code.

Comment: did your code look like this `$query->whereRaw('yearend - yearstart >= ?', [request('tempoh_negeri')]).groupBy('ID');`

Comment: $query->whereRaw('yearend - yearstart >= ?', [request('tempoh_negeri')])->groupBy('itemregistrations.ItemRegistrationID');

Comment: how about like this `$query->whereRaw('yearend - yearstart >= ?', [request('tempoh_negeri')])->groupBy('ID')->select('ID,Name,State,SUM(years) as years');`

Comment: where do you get (years) to be summed...the years is the output that should be queried..not the column in table..it is the value of whereRaw('yearend - yearstart)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this will work:

```
select m.id,m.name,sum(m.duration) from (select ID,Name,yearend-yearstart 
                      as duration from Table1)m group by  m.id,m.name;
```

check
:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9029438/4

Comment: your sql work nicely but I need to fit in laravel format..I need time to convert it

Comment: I accept your answer as your sql solve my query problem. I will find a way to convert them to laravel format. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    m.userid,
    m.name,
    m.state,
    SUM(m.yearend - m.yearstart) AS duration
FROM
    mytable m
GROUP BY m.userid , m.state , m.name;
```

I think this should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this !
select id,name,state,sum(years) years from table group by  ID

Comment: it  is not as simple as it is if you understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try SUM() on `years` column, then GROUP BY by `ID`, `Name`, and `State`.

This will aggregate the 'duplicated' rows that you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Please understand, the table is at the top not the below one. Please understand the question first..

Answer (score 0):

```
select name, state (max(yearend) - min(yearstart)) as years from state group by name;


+------+--------+------+
| name | state  | years |
+------+--------+------+
| Anne | Melaka |   10 |
| Bill | KL     |    1 |
| Tom  | Kedah  |    6 |
+------+--------+------+
```